# Maximum write rate to a document on Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to figure out, in real-time, each user's share of the cost of an item. Example:

```
/tickets/100/ticket-item/1:
{
  name: 'Red Dead Redemption'
  price: '5000'
  payers (array of maps): [
    {
      name: 'John', 
      share: '1666'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane', 
      share: '1667'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jack', 
      share: '1667'
    }
  ]
}
```

Given that the max write rate to a document is 1/second, will the write always fail if two users add themselves to the same ticket item doc at the exact same time?

I know that this can be mitigated to an extent by using transactions, but a transaction will only re-execute a finite number of times.  Let's say it re-executes up to 5 times.  If 6 users write to same ticket item doc at the exact same time, can I expect one of these writes to fail?

I would appreciate any and all advice regarding how to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the write always fail if two users add themselves to the same ticket item doc at the exact same time?

Yes it will. So if you are sure you'll have situations in which two or even more users will try to write/update data in a single document in the exact same time, I recommend you to be careful about this limitation because you might start to see some of this write operations to fail.

> I know that this can be mitigated to an extent by using transactions

It's a good idea but please be aware that transactions will fail when the client is offline.

> If 6 users write to same ticket item doc at the exact same time, can I expect one of these writes to fail?

As the docs states, a transaction will only re-execute a finite number of times. But please also note that in case of a [transaction failure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure):

> A failed transaction returns an error and does not write anything to the database.

So all you have to do is to take some action in case o transaction failure.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I remember reading documentation on the number of times a transaction will retry, but can't seem to find it anymore.  Do you know if it's actually 5 and is it configurable (I'm using angularfire2 if that matters)?

Comment: I cannot remember if it was actually a specific number of retries and as far as I know you cannot configure it. But you can restart the whole process once a transaction fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching same problem. 
May be like a solution: moving "payers" into separate collection with a ticket_id field?
So you'll have no limitations.